# How to MATCH based on values from multiple columns

Tags: formula, libreoffice-calc

My first table records characters from the book series A Song of Ice and Fire. My second table records characters who have *died* in A Song of Ice and Fire. In the fourth column in my first table, I want to test each row to see if there is a matching row on the second table; if so, that character can be said to have died. Here is invented sample data, so as not to spoil the series:

```
Characters table
+---------+---------+-----------+---------+
| Title   |  Name   |  Surname  | HasDied |
+---------+---------+-----------+---------+
| Ser     |  Jon    |  Skeet    |         |
| Lord    |  Jeff   |  Atwood   |         |
|         |  Leo    |  King     |         |
| Maester |  Joel   |  Spolsky  |         |
| Lady    | Experts | Exchange  |         |
+---------+---------+-----------+---------+

Death table
+---------+---------+-----------+
| Title   |  Name   |  Surname  |
+---------+---------+-----------+
|         |  Leo    |  King     |
| Ser     |  John   |  Doe      |
| Lady    | Experts | Exchange  |
+---------+---------+-----------+
```

In the `HasDied` column of the characters table, I want to check each value of that row - the `Title`, `Name`, `Surname`, and any other arbitrary fields - and if each of the values in the row being evaluated are found in a single row of the death table, then it would output true or false (or some other useful value.) So the characters table should look like this:

```
Characters table
+---------+---------+-----------+---------+
| Title   |  Name   |  Surname  | HasDied |
+---------+---------+-----------+---------+
| Ser     |  Jon    |  Skeet    |  FALSE  |
| Lord    |  Jeff   |  Atwood   |  FALSE  |
|         |  Leo    |  King     |  TRUE   |
| Maester |  Joel   |  Spolsky  |  FALSE  |
| Lady    | Experts | Exchange  |  TRUE   |
+---------+---------+-----------+---------+
```

I know that I can use MATCH to find any one value in the death table, but I can't just use three separate MATCH formulas for each column, it's important that the matching values are on the same row. How can I write a formula that would make this search? I'm using LibreOffice Calc, but Excel-based solutions are acceptable if you think they will work in Calc as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A suggestion for answering the original question in one go would be the array formula

=NOT(ISERROR(MATCH(CONCATENATE(A2,B2,C2),CONCATENATE(A$11:A$14,B$11:B$14,C$11:C$14),0)))

This concatenates the three parts of each name in the characters table and looks it up in an array formed by concatenating the three parts of each name in the death table.

Comment: Okay. So like what Zero suggested, but without the helper columns. Makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

This took some serious thinking, so I hope this is the answer you're looking for.

What the solution is in essence:

A series of nested IF statements, which have COUNTIF statements inside them, it basically checks if the for each column it can find that name in the second table. If it does, it will check the next column, etc. The logical test is if each column has a COUNTIF value greater than 0, then we know that character is dead.

Here is the formula, it assumes the tables are on top of each other in the same worksheet

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A$11:A$14,A2)>0,IF(COUNTIF(B$11:B$14,B2)>0,IF(COUNTIF(C$11:C$14,C2)>0,TRUE,FALSE),FALSE),FALSE)
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Okay, it works when all three columns are non-null. So it would provide the correct result for "Lady Experts Exchange", which has a title, forename and surname, but not for "Leo King", where the title field is blank. Can you think of any way to work around this? Otherwise it's a great idea :)

Comment: And if it wasn't clear, "Lady Experts Exchange" would output true, and "Leo King" would output false, while they should both output true.

Comment: To be honest with you, a much better work around is concatenate the cells with &&, then COUNTIF the character you want to check (so you concatenate in both tables) is in the dead table. But you would have to make a new column for both tables, but it should work fine.

Comment: Good point. I should have thought of that given that I already concatenated the cells...

Comment: I don't know, I'm on a train right now. I'll try it when I get home and report back.